# easiest way for users to include scalamacros paradise

Tags: scala, macros, sbt, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

I have just added some macro annotations to my library. In my library build, I include

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

to enable macro paradise.

In my users' projects that consume the macros, I know they need to include `scalamacros` somehow as well. Right now, in my example project, I do it the same as above. I was wondering if there was a briefer or less complicated way for the users to bring in the macros? For instance, is there some way I can leave off the `cross CrossVersion.full`? (As the user is probably not cross-compiling.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's as simple as it gets, really. Macro paradise versions are published against full Scala versions (like 2.11.8) rather than binary versions (like 2.11). `cross CrossVersion.full` ensures that the full `scalaVersion` from a build is appended to the artifact name, so assuming `scalaVersion := "2.11.8"`:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

becomes

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise_2.11.8" % "2.1.0")
```

It's simple enough to ask your users to include a single line in their build.